# DomPDF is deprecated in laravel project

Tags: laravel, dompdf

[image: app.php]

Does anyone knows why my DomPDF is deprecated in my laravel project? Help, thanks all.

Comment: The error tells you what to do, use `Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow suggestions ;)

```php
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf
```

Comment: Ah thanks, i didn't see it